# How to prevent RGB composite flatten to 1 band after raster calculation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator, rgb, band

I have a series of landsat wanting to process in raster calculator, but after doing the tool it happened these output images only contain one single band. They used to be RGB 3-band images.

It is on arcmap 10.3. I was using raster calculator to remove a certain value in my 3-band landsat image. After I type in the conditional statement to remove all 0 value from the inpur RGB image, it only returns an image of 1band, black and white. How can I preserve the RGB value in output.

Comment: It is on arcmap 10.3. I was using raster calculator to remove a certain value in my 3-band landsat image. After I type in the conditional statement to remove all 0 value from the inpur RGB image, it only returns an image of 1band, black and white. How can I preserve the RGB value in output.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply your conditions to each individual band then create a [composite band](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=composite_bands_%28data_management%29). This can be done on the fly (without storing the intermediate images) if you use the functions of the image analysis window.